# How to send() or transfer() from the contract address to an account address in solidity (I mean to deduct from address(this).balance)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

When the contract is deployed it has an address that we can call by address(this). My contract is receivable from an address which means I can send() or transfer() to this contract but If I want to transfer from this actual contract to any account how can I do that?

example code:

```
    function submitTransaction(address _to,uint _value,string memory _desc) public 
    onlyOwner 
    {
        require(_value <= address(this).balance,"This wallet does not have enough balace to send");
        if(!_to.send(_value)){
             revert("doposit fail");
        }
    }
```

but how can I deduct from address(this).balance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this example of smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Bank {
    address owner;
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You're not the smart contract owner!");
        _;
    }

    event Deposited(address from, uint amount);

    function depositMoney() public payable {
        emit Deposited(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    // Use transfer method to withdraw an amount of money and for updating automatically the balance
    function withdrawMoney(address _to, uint _value) public onlyOwner {
        payable(_to).transfer(_value);
    }

    // Getter smart contract Balance
    function getSmartContractBalance() external view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

**ADVICE**: In this case, if you want use only transfer or send, I advice you to use `transfer()` method instead `send()`, because it throws on failure if transfer didn't work. I recommend to read this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19341/address-send-vs-address-transfer-best-practice-usage). On the contrary for avoid reentracy attack you must to `call` method to transfer ether.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `safe` if you don't have a good reason, use `transfer` instead. While `transfer` will throw an error in case of a failure, the `safe` method will just return `false`, which means the next lines of the code will still be executed and the transaction will not be reverted if you don't handle the error.

```
function submitTransaction(address _to,uint _value,string memory _desc) public 
    onlyOwner 
    {
        require(_value <= address(this).balance,"This wallet does not have enough balace to send");
        _to.transfer(_value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (bool success, ) = addressToTransfer.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
 require(success, "Transfer failed.");
```